# Clarity on Code

Tags: php, mongodb

Just looking for some clarity on some code.

I'm looking at a Controller Class, it has a protected variables named $grid and inside there there is a __construct function to connect to MongoDB, after that there is this code:

```
$this->grid = $mongo->selectDB($database)->getGridFS();
```

Further on in in the script in another class and method I have the code

```
 foreach ($this->grid->find() as $file) {
```

Am I right in thinking that the foreach is using the first defined $this->grid being $monmgo->selectDB?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be worth reading up on [PHP5 objects and classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) as `__construct()`, `$this`, and the method call chaining are basic object-oriented implementation concepts in PHP.

The PHP method calls are chained in your code example, which means the results of one method are being passed into the next (from left to right).

```
 $this->grid = $mongo->selectDB($database)->getGridFS();
```

So this code executes as:

- [$mongo->selectDB($database)](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php) .. select database with name ($database); presumes that $mongo is successfully connected [Mongo object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php))
- Now, call [getGridFS()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.getgridfs.php) on the selected database
- Finally, assign the results of the last method call (`getGridFS()`) to variable `$this->grid`

`$this->grid` would end up being a new [MongoGridFS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongogridfs.php) object (based on the return type of `getGridFS()`.

The `foreach` is iterating on the results of the MongoGridFS object [`find()` method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongogridfs.find.php) which will be a [MongoGridFSCursor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongogridfscursor.php).